# Fixed Effect Model diagnostics using `fiest` package in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I recently noticed a wonderful R package `fixest` to run fixed effect estimation in R.

In conventional `plm` package, I know that we can run `pFtest()`, `pbptest()` and some diagnostics tests on estimated residuals. But, I was wondering to know whether it is possible to run the same diagnostic tests using the `fixest` package.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does its documentation tell you?

Comment: Well, seems the documentation shows all kinds of estimation approaches. I could not find anything relevant about the model diagnostics.